# How to click href javascript:void(0) and hidefocus=true with selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

How to click the href? [image]
I've tried

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/div/a[@id='switcher_plogin']")
```

I got an error like this:[image]
I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Use by id, you don't need the XPath here. Is it in an IFRAME? Have you tried adding a wait for clickable?

Answer (score 0):

To click on the link
Use `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable` along with following option.

**Xpath**:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='bottom_qlogin']/a[@id='switcher_plogin']"))).click()
```

**CSS Selector**:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#bottom_qlogin #switcher_plogin"))).click()
```

You need to imports following to execute above code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the link doesn't belong to [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), otherwise you will have to call [WebDriver.switch_to_frame](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to_frame) function first in order to change the context to the iframe where the link lives
2. Make sure that the link doesn't belong to [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) otherwise you will have to locate the relevant [ShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot) element first using [execute_script](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.event_firing_webdriver.EventFiringWebDriver.execute_script) function, cast the result to the WebElement and use WebElement's find() function to locate the link
3. It might be the case the link is not immediately present in [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) so you might need to introduce [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)
4. If there are no other elements having [ID attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp) of `switcher_plogin` you might want to reconsider the [locator strategy](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#locator-strategies) and stick to the ID instead of XPath.

Suggested code change:

replace this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/div/a[@id='switcher_plogin']")
```

with this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "switcher_plogin")))
```

References:

- [Selenium Python: Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)
- [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](http://How%20to%20use%20Selenium%20to%20test%20web%20applications%20using%20AJAX%20technology)
- You might also want to look at https://github.com/mgxian/qq_login/blob/master/lol_qq_login.py

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to `click()` on the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.link#switcher_plogin"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='link' and @id='switcher_plogin']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> **Note**: You can find a relevant discussion in [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)