# Selenium, Unable to click on JavaScript button

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I have checked on stack overflow and other websites to find the solution to my problem but nothing is working.     p
This was the closest solution I could fine but it didn't work
[How to click href javascript:void(0) and hidefocus=true with selenium python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57022726/how-to-click-href-javascriptvoid0-and-hidefocus-true-with-selenium-python)

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = uc.Chrome(version_main=106)
    driver.get("https://sneakernews.com/air-jordan-release-dates/")
    #
    # WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    #     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='content-box']"))
    #
    # )
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='sneaker-release-load-more-btn']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, ".//div[@class='more-button']/div/a[@id='sneaker-release-load-more-btn']")))
    jordan_names = driver.find_elements(By.ID,".//div[@class='more-button']/div/a[@id='sneaker-release-load-more-btn']")
print(jordan_names)
```

Could you please give me a direct solution that actually works for this particular example because I have spent many hours on this.

Comment: meeting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to click on the element using a JavaScript click - running a JavaScript click may or may not work depending on how the website is set up.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = uc.Chrome(version_main=106)
    driver.get("https://sneakernews.com/air-jordan-release-dates/")
    clickable_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@id='sneaker-release-load-more-btn']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", clickable_element)
```